dejustify (unjustify): replace each *single* linefeed with a space, but don't touch groups of linefeeds. sed, awk, or something else?
I'm looking for a linux command-line solution to the problem:
"Replace each single linefeed with a space, but don't modify any groups of consecutive linefeeds i.e. do not modify any linefeed which has another linefeed next to it." As an example:
one two
three four
five six

seven eight
nine ten

should become:
one two three four five six

seven eight nine ten

I am already aware that every valid text file should end with a linefeed, but if your proposed solution deletes that final-character-linefeed, that would not be a problem (it would be easy for me to append it back on afterwards).
I think that this is "too complex a task" for tr, but I assume something should be possible in sed or awk (if not, then I'll need to "rustle up" something in python or c). Unfortunately, my sed-fu is weak (as is my awk-fu) - are there any sed/awk black-belts around that could please help me?
I have already found How can I replace each newline (\n) with a space using sed? but of course the suggested answers to that question wipe out my "multiple consecutive linefeeds" (which I want to preserve).
I am also aware that "Sed is line-based therefore it is hard for it to grasp newlines" - perhaps sed is not the best tool for this job.
I have also found Replace only single instance of a character using sed but of course the character being replaced in that question is not a (problematic) linefeed.
(Why do I want this? The nano editor has a justify function which adds and removes single linefeeds so that any line "fills" the chosen line length but does not overrun it. nano does have a "built-in" unjustify function, but this is really just an "undo", not a "real" unjustify. What I am trying to find is the closest thing to a "genuine" unjustify command.)
Update: all the current solutions work perfectly, and thank you to all those who provided them. I've accepted Ed Morton's for the reasons that he gives - his processes only 1 line of input at a time, and it's portable to a non-gnu version of its tool. The solution to my nano problem is:
cat << 'EOF' > $HOME/.local/bin/dejustify
#!/bin/sh
awk -v RS= 'NR>1{print ""} {$1=$1} 1' < "${1:-/dev/stdin}"
EOF
chmod u+x $HOME/.local/bin/dejustify

(I found the < "${1:-/dev/stdin}" here.)
I can now use it in a pipeline (printf "one\ntwo\nthree\nfour\n" | dejustify) or just dejustify <filename>.
Inside nano, I can <Ctrl>+<t> then enter |dejustify to dejustify my text. Success! 

Using any awk:
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' -F'\n' '{$1=$1} 1' file
one two three four five six

seven eight nine ten


Breaking it down:

-v RS= treat the input as [possibly multi-line] records separated by 1 or more empty lines.
-v ORS='\n\n' put 2 newlines at the end of each output record.
-F'\n' set the field separator to a newline so that ONLY newlines get replaced in the next step, otherwise all chains of contiguous white space within each record would be replaced.
{$1=$1} update the value of a field, $1, thereby causing awk to rebuild the current record replacing all strings that match the FS (a newline) with an OFS (a blank char).
1 a true condition causing awk to execute it's default action of printing the current record.

The above will print a blank line at the end of the output, if that's a problem you can always do this instead:
$ awk -v RS= -F'\n' 'NR>1{print ""} {$1=$1} 1' file
one two three four five six

seven eight nine ten

which prints a blank line before each record except the first instead of printing a blank line after every record:

NR>1{print ""} if this is the second or subsequent record then print a blank line before it.


I've been working on my question for over 8 hours, and you answer it in 1 minute and 40 seconds. Me speechless!

@jaimet that's what happens when you put a lot of effort into formulating a good question, it's easy for us to provide a good answer.

Although this is a neat answer it perhaps does not fully respect the problem as it squeezes all newlines.

@potong D'oh - you are correct. I didn't spot this due to insufficient testing on my behalf. I need to think this over for a bit...

@EdMorton Is there any easy modification to your "version 2" which does not squeeze linefeed groups?

set FS='\n' to avoid squeezing non-newline whitespace ?

@jaimet I updated it to only replace newlines with blanks.

This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed -E ':a;N;s/([^\n])\n([^\n])/\1 \2/;ta;P;D' file

Append the next line and if the introduced newline is separated by non-newlines, replace the newline with a space and repeat.
Print up to and including the first newline.
Delete up to and including the first newline.
Repeat.

Alternatives perhaps:
sed ':a;N;s/\>\n\</ /;ta;P;D' file

Or:
sed ':a;N;s/\b\n\b/ /;ta;P;D' file


or sed -e :a -e 'N;/.\n./s/\n/ /;ta' -e 'P;D' file

Cyrus added an answer which unfortunately did not produce the desired effect, but potong then added a comment (to Cyrus's answer) which included another different correct solution. Cyrus then deleted his answer which also deleted potong's comment - I want to preserve potong's different correct solution so I am adding it back in here:
sed -Ez 's/([^\n])\n([^\n])/\1 \2/g' file # suggested by potong


You should mention that that a) requires GNU sed and b) would read the whole input file into memory at once (as does Daweo's perl solution) and so YMMV depending on how large the input is. The sed answer potong posted still requires GNU sed but doesn't read the whole file into memory at once so that would be better if you were going to use sed (but is still not as simple and portable as the awk solution).

replace each single linefeed with a space, but don't touch groups of linefeeds
This might be achieved using regular expression with zero-length assertions. I would use perl as there is high chance it is already installed in linux machine. Let file.txt content be
one two
three four
five six

seven eight
nine ten

then
perl -p -0777 -e 's/(?<=[^\n])\n(?=[^\n])/ /g' file.txt

gives output
one two three four five six

seven eight nine ten

Explanation: I engage sed mode (-p -e) with treating whole file as single giant line (-0777), then I substitute every (g like globally) \n after non-newline character and before non-newline character using space. This solution does not remove last newline.
(tested in v5.34.0)

An awk method that only converts standalone linefeeds to space, without squeezing any other whitespace:
awk '
  BEGIN { ORS = "" }
  {
    thislen = length
    print ( thislen && prevlen ? FS : NR>1 ? RS : "" ) $0
    prevlen = thislen
  }
  END { print RS }
' file


print every input line, without any trailing newline
prepend either:

a space (both current and previous line are not empty); or
a newline (this is not first line); or
nothing (this is first line)


finish by appending a trailing newline

Applying to:
one  two
 three four
five   six

seven eight
nine  ten


  eleven
     twelve



thirteen

gives:
one  two  three four five   six

seven eight nine  ten


  eleven      twelve



thirteen

